# Transforming a variable when original variable does not have explantory power

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, linear-model

Sometimes in multivariate linear regression, there will be one explanatory variable that does not contribute much in way of explanatory power. Then, we will perform a tranform on that variable, i.e take the log, scale it by some factor etc. and suddenly this variable now has explanatory power and is deemed fit to be included in the model.

Is this a good practice? i.e Simply transform a variable to make it look like it has explanatory power? Does experience in the domain guide what needs tobe done with the variable...i.e exclude it or include it after a transformation?

Comment: "*Then, we will perform a transform on that variable*" -- or if a reasonable transformation was already used before we begin fitting models (say from theory, or even just basic consideration of the particular situation), perhaps the variable is simply not much use. Or, absent good theory or ideas, we might data dredge, if we don't make the cardinal mistake of evaluating the model on the data we used to identify it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends on if you are a purist, a pragmatist, or a data dredger.

The purist will only ever try one transformation, and that is based only on the science and previous knowledge and will be chosen before any data is collected (or looked at).  This is the safest approach, but can also loose out on gaining insight from the data.

The data dredger will try every possible transformation until they find one that gives them the answer that they want.  This can result in impressive results, but also ends in over fitting models and unreproducible results.

The pragmatist (the largest and most productive group) recognizes that there are things that we can learn from the data, but also is wary of over fitting the data.  They will look at a few possible transforms that are justified by the science, or try splines or other smooths with a reasonable smoothness constraint.  They will also do things like cross-validation to make sure that their experimenting has not resulted in over fitting and reign things back if it has.  They will then also be honest about what they did (explaining which transforms were experimented with in the discussion) and look for validation in a follow-up study.

I recommend the pragmatic approach.

Comment: I agree, but would put the last sentence of the last paragraph ("They will then also be honest ...") in **bold**.  It's a slippery slope.

Answer (score 1):

It's a legitimate practice you are describing. As a matter of fact, having all variables linear is a simplification out of necessity. Usually, we don't know what is a true relationship between variables, so we model them linearly.

If you happen to know the relationships, often non-linear, then definitely go for it.

Here's an example, where the true process is $y_t=sin(\beta t)+\varepsilon_t$. First I model it with $y_t=\beta' t+\varepsilon_t$, then model with a proper specification. In the first case the coefficient comes not significant, in the second case it's significant.

MATLAB Code:

```
rng(0);
x = (1:100)'/100*pi;
% data generating process
y = sin(x) + randn(100,1)/2;

% fit linear x
fit = fitlm(x,y)

% fit sin(x)
fit2 = fitlm(sin(x),y)

plot([y fit.Fitted fit2.Fitted])
legend({'actual' ,'fitted x','fitted sin x'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
fit = 


Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1

Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate       SE        tStat       pValue  
                   ________    ________    _______    __________

    (Intercept)     0.89621     0.12771     7.0177    2.9539e-10
    x1             -0.12487    0.069885    -1.7868      0.077068


Number of observations: 100, Error degrees of freedom: 98
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.634
R-squared: 0.0315,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.0217
F-statistic vs. constant model: 3.19, p-value = 0.0771

fit2 = 


Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1

Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate      SE       tStat       pValue  
                   ________    _______    ______    __________

    (Intercept)    0.13799     0.13389    1.0306       0.30527
    x1             0.87991     0.18936    4.6468    1.0507e-05


Number of observations: 100, Error degrees of freedom: 98
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.583
R-squared: 0.181,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.172
F-statistic vs. constant model: 21.6, p-value = 1.05e-05
```

> > [image]

Comment: Thanks. But how did you choose a sin function to transform your variable as opposed to countless possible other transformations?

Comment: @Victor, that's the point of having some kind of theory or domain knowledge. For instance, when i used to be a physicist, I usually had a very good idea of what kind of relationship to expect. In social sciences this is a big problem, we usually have no clue, so finding the proper transformation is a challenge

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to match the OP's question, which is about (presumably) monotonic transformations of explanatory variables (rather than alternative model specifications) -- admittedly these are very close, but I don't think they're identical.

Comment: @BenBolker, he never mentioned monotonic. He asked a general question about linearity and transformations. The point is still the same: if you have a theory which asks for transformation, you don't need to fit the linear model.

Comment: I agree it's a similar question, *but* ... narrowly speaking, I don't see how your answer relates to a transformation of an explanatory variable.  How would you transform `t`, or `x1` in your example? Arc-cosine-transforming could be problematic ...

Comment: @BenBolker, the most familiar example is decibel. You could measure sound pressure in Pascals, which is a standard unit of measure for pressure. Then you might try to build a model for acoustics, and you'll quickly realize that it's better to take the log. In this case it doesn't make a sense to use straight Pascals, because our sensitivity to the sound is logarithmic. So, the domain asks us to apply the transform.

Comment: I completely agree with your analysis and examples.  I just don't think (unless you take sound pressure as an *explanatory* variable in your last example) that they match the OP's question very precisely.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely good practice! If the true relationship between your response and the explanatory variables is logarithmic then your model ought to reflect this. Of course, we never know for sure the nature of the true relationship so we do things like plot the data or fit the model in different ways (with and without a log transformation) and assess fit.

Comment: Thanks, my point is...do just keep transforming the variable i.e x1 = Log(log(log......(logx) until x1 has some explanatory power? Like a trial and error process? Or does domain experience guide us what (if any) tranformations to apply.

Comment: It is certainly possible that there is a very convoluted relationship between your Y and X variables like the log(log(log())) relationship you mention. I think the best practice is to plot your data - does a scatterplot of Y and X suggest a linear relationship? If not, consider a log transformation. Does a scatterplot of Y and log(x) suggest a linear relationship? If not, consider a log(log()) transformation, etc.

Comment: Bear in mind, Victor, if you do something like x1 = Log(log(log......(logx) and then need to communicate your results to an audience, say, in an academic paper, you'd ought to justify the transformation(s). Otherwise, the process you describe could be seen as blatant data mining. In the vast majority of cases, you'd do well to employ a sound modelling strategy rather than get into the realm of ad hockery. Questions to ask oneself, and not to forget, are _what is the purpose of the model?_ and _what is the research question?_.

Comment: Regression is a first order linear approximation of the conditional mean. If one monotone transform doesn't capture that relationship, none of them will. Source is my own experience, but file this under "simulation studies I'll eventually get around to"